# 3D View from coordinate x,y,z in Paraview

Tags: csv, visualization, paraview

I am a new comer in Paraview and would like to ask how I can make a 3D view of a reservoir. I have also read some previous articles that the best way is possibly to apply a filter "Alphabetical -> Delaunay 2D" (e.g. [Displaying an Elevation grid in ParaView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809758/displaying-an-elevation-grid-in-paraview)).

I have also tried it; unfortunately, since my domain is not a rectangular, there were some useless triangulars which were formed outside main domain. In the link above, it can be used easily since the domain is a rectangular. The input file is (.csv file):

```
"x", "y", "z"               
-38.82  ,   36.14   ,   2.00
-38.82  ,   39.04   ,   2.00
-38.82  ,   41.93   ,   2.00
-38.89  ,   44.70   ,   2.00
-38.96  ,   47.47   ,   2.00
-38.96  ,   49.51   ,   2.00
-38.96  ,   51.55   ,   2.00
-31.05  ,   39.01   ,   2.00
-31.05  ,   36.14   ,   2.00
-31.05  ,   41.89   ,   2.00
-31.10  ,   44.63   ,   2.00
-31.14  ,   47.38   ,   2.00
-31.14  ,   49.47   ,   2.00
-31.14  ,   51.55   ,   2.00
-23.28  ,   38.99   ,   2.00
-23.28  ,   36.14   ,   2.00
-23.28  ,   41.84   ,   2.00
-23.30  ,   44.57   ,   2.00
-23.33  ,   47.29   ,   2.00
-23.33  ,   49.42   ,   2.00
-23.33  ,   51.55   ,   2.00
-15.51  ,   38.97   ,   2.00
-15.51  ,   36.14   ,   2.00
-15.51  ,   41.80   ,   5.00
-15.51  ,   44.50   ,   5.00
-15.51  ,   47.20   ,   5.00
-15.51  ,   49.38   ,   2.00
-15.51  ,   51.55   ,   2.00
-9.61   ,   44.50   ,   5.00
-9.63   ,   41.80   ,   5.00
-9.58   ,   47.20   ,   5.00
-3.70   ,   44.50   ,   5.00
-3.75   ,   41.80   ,   5.00
-3.66   ,   47.20   ,   5.00
2.20    ,   44.50   ,   5.00
2.13    ,   41.80   ,   5.00
2.27    ,   47.20   ,   5.00
-15.51  ,   47.20   ,   2.00
-15.51  ,   44.50   ,   2.00
-15.51  ,   41.80   ,   2.00
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The domain you are trying to display is non-convex. The Delaunay 2D has no way to know whether those non-convex regions (those empty regions from about -15 to 2 along the X axis) are supposed to be part of the domain or not. So the Delaunay 2D filter makes the simple assumption that the region is supposed to be convex and fills in those regions. Like it or not, I don't think anyone knows a more robust way to determine the bounds of a region when given nothing but a set of points.

I notice another issue with your data and Delaunay 2D. It looks like there are 3 pairs of points that share (x,y) coordinates. I assume this is supposed to form a vertical shelf, but instead Delaunay 2D is ignoring some of them because they have the same (x,y) coordinates. As the name implies, Delaunay 2D projects all the points to the x-y plane and does a 2D Delaunay triangulation. Any points with the same (x,y) coordinates will be treated the same.

To get this to work with Delauny 2D, you will need to make some corrections. First, you will need to offset the points on that shelf in the x direction so that they do not have the same (x,y) coordinate. This is probably most easily done by editing your input. Second, you will have to manually remove the "extraneous" polygons generated outside of the domain. You can do that by making selections in the 3D window and then extracting the selection.

Another option is to write out your data in a different format that captures the mesh you want to represent. Although not square, your domain is fairly simple. It should be pretty easy to define quadrilaterals or triangles that connect the points. You can write them into a VTK legacy data set (http://www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf), which is not much more complicated than writing out a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Loading your .csv and applying "Table to Points" or "Table to Structured Grid" will help you if you just want to see the structure

Writing your data to .vtk will be more useful if you will work on the reservoir file. Adding atributtes to it and so...